# Facebook Marketing API: system user permission missing

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing an app in our CRM to automate ads creation.
I've created a system user in BM and assigned our ad account granting full control. Then I've generated a new token adding following scopes:

```
business_management
ads_management
ads_read
read_insights
```

When I try to use the token to make API calls I receive a missing permission error:

```
{"message":"(#100) Missing permissions","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A-IpQXM5LOuHkbvN64tZ2wD"}
```

I've checked in Access Token Debugger and scopes field is empty as if no scope has been added but during token creation I receive no errors.

Please note that in App Developer Dashboard I've added API Marketing and set App in LIVE mode. Nevertheless under settings in API Marketing I get the following message:

```
Ads API access level:development
Possible reasons for current access level:
App unapproved for "Ads Management Standard Access"
```

I don't know if it's related to missing permissions.
What am I missing? Thank you for any suggestions